# Stata failed to load the share library python39.dll

Tags: python, stata

I'm trying to call Python from Stata. It was working without any problems, until I recently updated Python. Now, when I try to call Python from Stata I get the following error:

> failed to load the shared library C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python39.dll

My Stata version is 16.1. Python version is 3.9.10.

Answer (score 2):

Downgrading version of Python to 3.8.12 solved the issue.

Comment: Not sure that this was solved

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem when I use python3.10.9, and then I downgrade python to 3.9.17, it is solved. Seems Stata don't support the latest version of python.

Comment: You're going to get a definitive answer on that only by getting StataCorp to comment. Using Statalist for a query or emailing StataCorp Technical Services would be ways  to do that.